# JavaScript Splitting a Value Separated by an Underscore and Calculating SUM

Tags: javascript

I've used **var.split("_");** here. Example of a value I'm trying to get would be: **2_25000**

However, below code results a NaN value.

```
function calculateTotal() {
    var room_type_id = document.getElementById('room_type_id').value;
    var room_type_cost = room_type_id.split("_");

    var meal_type_id = document.getElementById('meal_type_id').value;
    var meal_type_cost = meal_type_id.split("_");

    var bed_type_id = document.getElementById('bed_type_id').value;
    var bed_type_cost = bed_type_id.split("_");

    var ext_beds_id = document.getElementById('ext_beds_id').value;
    var reservation_duration = document.getElementById('reservation_duration').value;

    document.getElementById('total_amount').value = ( Number(room_type_cost[1]) + Number(meal_type_cost[1]) + Number(bed_type_cost[1]) + Number(ext_beds_id) ) * Number(reservation_duration);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you may use number() function or parseInt() function but remember to also pass the base 10 second parameter in parseInt("23", 10), also you can prefix + symbol to convert it to integer.
for i.e., `+"23" + 2`

Comment: I followed your suggestion. It worked! Weirdly though, now it passes correct calculation if I select #meal_type_id input (multiselect) in the first place. If I select #room_type_id or #bed_type_id dropdowns, it gives a NaN.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one............

change

```
Number()
```

to

```
parseInt()
```